# Is it possible to create a shortcut to a flash disk in Windows CE?

Tags: directory, windows-ce, handheld

We are switching devices, and the flash disks are name differently, but our software's configuration files are written with that directory hardcoded (not like we would ever change vendors, right?)

So...is it possible to create a shortcut to the new flash disk with the name of the old one such that I don't have to change all the paths?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no (well not easily).  Shortcuts files in CE are very simple text files of the folowing format:

```
25#\program files\myapp.exe
```

Where the number at the start is the number of characters in the path following, including the hash.  You can change the target by changing the path text, but there's no easy way to "virtually map" one location to another.

Now there *is* a way that you could achieve remapping, but it requires that you write, deploy and install a [file-system filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885434.aspx) (FSF).  An FSF could "forward" requests from one location to another.  However, it seems (to me anyway) that you're going to have to configure that FSF with the device-specific path, and it's probably easier to just change your shortcuts.

If it were my problem to solve, I'd likely create an app that reads the [registry for the storage driver profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892393.aspx) to determine its name for the card, then modify the shortcuts with that text.

Comment: Excellent... It seems like relative paths don't work, either.

Comment: No.  Ce doesn't support relative paths, they must be absolute.